# How do I structure Django folders with multiple tables?

Tags: django

I am getting confused as to how I should structure the folders for an app that uses four tables. Should I make a different urls.py for each table and put them in a folder? Should I include views.py in each folder? What about forms.py?

My structure is this:
db_project  -->  db_app

Under db_app there is a database with 4 tables, we'll just call them a, b, c, and d. Each table has a form to add data to the table as well as a list view.

Should I create an a, b, c, and d folder under db_app, then make urls, views, and forms in each one? Or should I just make one file with all the info for the 4 tables in it and just handle all the routing in a single urls.py file under db_app?

Also, could I just make 4 urls.py files in the same folder and name them a_urls.py etc? Or does Django require the name to be strictly urls.py?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not necessary or desirable.  If all the forms and tables (models) are logically part of the same application, then keep them all together under your db_app.

Put your four table definitions (models.Model subclasses) into models.py, your four forms into forms.py, all your views in views.py, and all the urls for those views into urls.py.

If you write some code which is logically separate from the code you are writing now, eg a totally independent app or an app that is related but which represents a whole different set of functionality, then make another app folder (using manage.py startapp).

BTW if you need to access the models in one app from another app, you can do that, it's not a problem.  You would just import the model class from one app into the other eg: `from app3.models import MySharedModel`.  But in this case you don't seem to need that just yet.

But let's say you wrote an app for maintaining a database of all your clothing, then you wrote one for maintaining a list of recipes.. these are unlikely to share any data.  But the auth app is used by both for logging in.  If you were to make an event calendar app for yourself, then who knows.. maybe you would have a dependency between the calendar app and the clothing app so that the clothing app could remind you that your favorite summer suit needs to go to the cleaners the week before the wedding...

A typical folder layout would be:

```
# the main project folder, containing manage.py
myproject/
# the main app, 
# which contains your master settings.py and also master urls.py
# it can also contain views, models etc and have full app functionality
myproject/myproject
# a second app
# this also contains all the same files as usual but does not need
# settings.py, which is gotten from the myproject/myproject/settings.py
myproject/app2
# a third app
myproject/app3

# your myproject/myproject/urls.py:
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
import app2.urls
import app3.urls    

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^app2/', include('app2.urls')),
    url(r'^app3/', include('app3.urls')),
)
```

And then also, you would have 'app2' and 'app3' in your INSTALLED_APPS list in the yourproject/yourproject/settings.py

In this example, the 'master' app has no urls of it's own but it totally can have them.  It is also not necessary to have multiple apps you can do everything in one if that makes sense for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem I'm still having is how to route the urls.  There will be url.com/a, url.com/b etc, each with /new, /edit, etc. If I handle the /a /b ... parts in the project urls.py, they will not be passed to the app urls.py, and I would have to use different names. Do I have to make separate urls.py files?

Comment: The folder structure that django encourages you to use (the path of least resistance) is a master myprojectname project folder with at least one app folder also called myprojectname.. and this will be your 'master' app which contains settings.py and your master urls.py.  This can be your ONLY app in which case its urls.py would contain the urls for all your views.  If it is not your only app, your master urls.py can include the urls.py for all your other apps.